# How to modify query so that it can work on bunch of weeks automatically?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a query which returns data for `week_number 2` as shown below. It uses `week_number` from the innermost query.

```sql
SELECT
    type,
    total
FROM 
    xyz.orders pa
JOIN
    (SELECT
         clientid AS clientid,
         MAX(version) AS version
     FROM
         xyz.orders
     WHERE 
         consumerid IN (SELECT entity_id
                        FROM abc.items
                        WHERE week_number IN (2)
                          AND item_type like '%Ionize - Data%')
         AND createdfor = 'BLOCK'
         AND holder = 'RELAY_FUTURES'
    GROUP BY 
        clientid) pb ON (pa.clientid = pb.clientid AND pa.version = pb.version);
```

Now if I need to get data for `week_number 3` then I just change 2 to 3 in my innermost query and it works. Similarly I can change to any other week I want in the same way in my innermost query.

**Problem Statement**

Now for each week I need to modify my above query manually and run it separately to get data which is kinda pain. Is there any way I can put all the week_number I want data for in the above query and then my query can group them accordingly instead of running separately for each week manually in my original query? Is this possible to do by any chance?

Expected Output:

```
week   type     total
----------------------
 2     TEST1    1768
 2     TEST1    1231
 2     TEST2    1890
 2     TEST2    2223
 2     TEST3    1981
 2     TEST3    8818
 3     TEST1    1111
 3     TEST1    8765
 3     TEST2    9999
 3     TEST2    1524
 3     TEST3    5565
 3     TEST3    1897
 ...........
 ..........
 ............
```

I tried like this but it is not providing same data as I get from my above manual query for each week. What is wrong in my below query? If my below query is completely wrong then what's the best way to do above things?

```
SELECT pb.week_number,
       pa.type,
       pa.total
FROM   xyz.orders pa
       JOIN (SELECT MaxVersions.week_number,
                    O.clientid     AS clientid,
                    Max(O.version) AS version
             FROM   xyz.orders O
                    JOIN (SELECT entity_id,
                                 week_number
                          FROM   abc.items
                          WHERE  week_number IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5 )
                                 AND item_type LIKE '%Ionize - Data%')
                         MaxVersions
                      ON entity_id = consumerid
                         AND O.createdfor = 'BLOCK'
                         AND O.holder = 'RELAY_FUTURES'
             GROUP  BY O.clientid,
                       MaxVersions.week_number) pb
         ON pa.clientid = pb.clientid
            AND pa.version = pb.version
```

Comment: if you can, please also provide sample data and your current output :)

Comment: Data is very huge like 40-50k rows for each week so it will be very difficult to provide.